# Origin of Grothendieck universes

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, set-theory

Does anyone know in what paper Grothendieck universes were first introduced? I looked at Grothendieck's [1957 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178244839). I can't read French so I am not entirely sure, but I couldn't find any definitions similar to that of Grothendieck universes in that paper. Did I simply miss it, or are Grothendieck universes first introduced in a different paper? I expect that if Grothendieck was the one to introduce Grothendieck universes, then he defined them under a different name.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no occurrence of the word "universe" (_univers_ in French) in Tohoku. Again as far as I know, the definition was first given in SGA4.

Comment: There was a big bang, and then the universe had to cool down, etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grothendieck universes were first introduced at the beginning of the Chapter 1 titled "Préfaisceaux" ([page 185](http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/4-1/4-1t_185.html)) of:

Grothendieck, A., & Verdier, J. L. (1972). Volume 1 of *Théorie des Topos et Cohomologie Etale des Schémas. Séminaire de Géométrie Algébrique du Bois-Marie 1963-1964 (SGA 4)*. Lecture Notes in Mathematics. doi:10.1007/bfb0081551

Answer (score 5):

The first use of Grothendieck universes that I'm aware of is in Zermelo's 1930 paper "Über Grenzzahlen und Mengenbereiche" (Fundamenta Mathematicae 16, pp. 29–47). But there might be earlier occurrences of the concept, most likely in work of von Neumann in the 1920's.

Comment: Where in that paper are Grothendieck universes discussed?

Comment: @Anonymous Essentially the whole paper is about what Zermelo calls "Normalbereiche", which are now called "Grothendieck universes" (except that the latter are required to also satisfy the axiom of infinity, so the Normalbereich of hereditarily finite sets i excluded). The formal definition of "Normabereich" is at the beginning of Section 3, but the concept is described already in the paper's first paragraph. (Zermelo allows atoms (= Urelemente) in his universes, but specializing to the case of an empty set of atoms gives the current picture of pure sets.)